# Why does VPN IPSec client use UDP?

Tags: vpn, udp

The VPN I use on my home Windows computer to connect to my company's servers is a Cisco client. The client is configured to use "IPSec over UDP (NAT/PAT)".

Why would you use UDP, an "unreliable" protocol, for a secure tunnel? Wouldn't the unreliability of the protocol cause problems when UDP packets are dropped?

Or is the protocol using UDP but adding reliability at the application layer?

Comment: IP is also an "unreliable" protocol.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It uses UDP to get through minimally featured NAT devices. What's happening here is that the actual IPSec traffic is being encapsulated in UDP ([IP protocol](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml) 17). The native IPSec packet would have an IP protocol header-value of 50. Since 50 is neither UDP (17) or TCP (6), naive NAT gateways will drop the packet rather than pass it.

Secondly, since IPSec is neither TCP or UDP, it doesn't have a port-number. So if you're at a very large conference and eight of your coworkers are also going, only one of you could have your VPN up at any time as the VPN Concentrator only does IP-level disambiguation. By encapsulating inside of a UDP packet, it allows multiple VPN end-points behind a NAT device.

As for why UDP? That's described in [RFC 3715](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3715). Section 2.1.b:

> Incompatibility between checksums and NAT.  TCP and UDP checksums
> have a dependency on the IP source and destination addresses
> through inclusion of the "pseudo-header" in the calculation.  As a
> result, where checksums are calculated and checked upon receipt,
> they will be invalidated by passage through a NAT or reverse NAT
> device.

> As a result, IPsec Encapsulating Security Payload (ESP) will only
> pass through a NAT unimpeded if TCP/UDP protocols are not involved
> (as in IPsec tunnel mode or IPsec protected GRE), or checksums are
> not calculated (as is possible with IPv4 UDP).  As described in
> [RFC793], TCP checksum calculation and verification is required in
> IPv4.  UDP/TCP checksum calculation and verification is required
> in IPv6.

This can happen since the IPSec stack itself has integrity checking, so using an 'unreliable' protocol to transit networks does not present a critical breakage in functionality. If a packet gets scrambled in-transit, it won't de-encapsulate right, and the IPSec protocol will correctly handle that case.

Some clients do support TCP mode, but Cisco isn't one of them.

Comment: Also, [TCP Over TCP Is A Bad Idea](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html)